# Moment.js diff wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date and I want to substract today of this date. This is my example:

```
date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
"2018-04-07"
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
"2018-04-06"
date.diff(moment(), 'days')
0
```

The `diff` call returns 0 instead of 1. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you show what is `date`?

Comment: What is *date*? How is it created?

Comment: date = new Date(...);

Answer (score 4):

> By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal
>   places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number,
>   pass true as the third argument. Before 2.0.0, moment#diff returned a
>   number rounded to the nearest integer, not a truncated number.

To see the full value, pass true as the third parameter:

```
 now.diff(date, 'days', true)
```

If you want to compare just dates, then use:

var now = moment().startOf('day');

which will set the time to 00:00:00 in the local time zone. And compare with date

Answer (score 2):

Use [fromNow()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) function to understand why you are getting `0` instead of `1`. It is very straight-forward.

Do like this :

`moment(date).fromNow();`

It will give you number of days passed if time is greater than 24 hours otherwise it will give to time in hours. e.g. 2 hours ago, 23 hours etc.

Below is example:

```js
console.log(moment("2018-04-06", "YYYY-MM-DD").fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

So you can see it is returning `18 hours ago` (as of now) which is less than 24hours i.e. 1 day.

I would suggest to use `fromNow` instead of `diff` to get exact difference.

Hope now it makes clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

`moment()` returns a full moment including time, so it's doing a diff from today, including time, to midnight of the 7th of April, which isn't a full day.

Comment: But therefore I say  .diff(..., 'days'). The time should be ignored.Am I correct?

Comment: It calculates the precise difference, in milliseconds I believe, converts it to the necessary unit, and then returns an integer by removing the truncating decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. So after a few research on StackOverflow and moment.js documentation I came up with this solution. Works perfectly for me.

```
const date1 = "2021-05-12T06:30:00.000Z"
const date2 = "2021-05-18T06:30:00.000Z"

const day1 = moment((moment(date1).format("YYYY-MM-DD")).split("-"))
const day2 = moment((moment(date2).format("YYYY-MM-DD")).split("-"))


const diff = day2.diff(day1,'days')
```